# How to verify information in Carthage.resolved?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage

Cocoapods embed a step in the build phase to check if the Pods folder is in sync with the versions in Podfile.lock. This blocks the developer to work with the stale versions of the Pod with the following error:

> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod
> install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Carthage has Cartfile.resolved, but how is it used to check if the Carthage Builds are fresh vs stale? Is it something that has to be manually enforced via some script?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the Carthage guides do not mention this topic at all. Usually you will be informed via failing compilation that a certain framework is not found, e.g. if you switched to a new branch where a new feature is implemented that needs framework XYZ. Then you know you have to run `carthage bootstrap`.

We have a script that runs so fast that you could even place it into the git hooks so it runs automatically after switching branches. The carthage part just cann the following command:

```
carthage bootstrap --use-ssh --use-xcframeworks --cache-builds
```

It makes sure carthage is up to date and it is fast since it uses cached builds. Runs fine for several years now.